# Andengine Sprite no longer visible after switching scenes

Tags: java, android, andengine

again I have a problem where I think I have tried everything and nothing is working so I am asking you for any ideas :)

**Here it is:**

In my AndEngine game I switch scenes. First I have my *gameScene* where my *Sprite* is walking around, then I detach the Sprite and switch to *another scene* [using `mEngine.setScene(otherScene)`] where he gets attached again. This works like a charm until I switch back to the gameScene.

I *detach* the sprite from that other scene, *switch* back [again using `mEngine.setScene(gameScene)`] and after some time (there is a TimerHandler involved) the Sprite gets *attached* to that gameScene again. **But it is not visible.**

Here are some things I could think of, why this could fail... but everything checks out so far:

- Sprite **attached** to the correct Scene
- correct **Position** (the same position he came from the first time)
- correct **Size** of the sprite (32x32 pixels)
- `setVisible(true);`  (doesn't work, with  or without)
- **zIndex** (set to the one it had before or set to something higher...)
- the **Alpha** value like with `setAlpha(1f);` for full visibility
- the sprite has it's own **TextureAtlas** (1024x1024) <-- I know, its huge - but it worked before :)
- I even tried reloading the **texture** (`textureAtlas.load()`)

nothing worked so far - I double checked each of these settings (by logging it, setting it and logging it again ...)

Now I am completely lost. The thing is, that everything works fine so far. The sprite was moving around and I had no problems switching scenes... I even switched a second time back to that other scene and the sprite was there again... but not in the gameScene - not even a black square or something just nothing.

Oh and i can track the sprite while he is moving. With the **camera following the sprite** I see that he is doing what he is supposed to do - he is just invisible.

Any more ideas? What am I missing here? Did any of you have experienced something similar?
Anyway, thanks for taking the time and reading this!

best regards

Christoph

Answer (score 2):

Try calling `engineOptions.getRenderOptions().disableExtensionVertexBufferObjects();` before you create the Engine. I had problems similar to this and it turned out that this option forces the RAM and GPU to keep getting synchronized which somehow (I have yet to learn the principles of OpenGL) prevented the Sprites from disappearing.

Comment: thanks, I appreciate this. Unfortunately this options is no longer available in AndEngine GLES 2.0 (sorry I didn't say it earlier, that I am using that version). I searched the engine options for something similar but couldn't find anything. Neither could I find anything about this with google. Do you know how to force that synchronization in AndEngine GLES 2 ?

Comment: No idea, I am stuck with GLES1 for now.

Comment: thanks for your help. I will keep looking, now that I know what to look for :)